# Can I protect a Windows driver from being unloaded?

Tags: windows, kernel, driver

I'm developing a software driver for software protection and I would like to be able to prevent my driver from being unloaded without internal checks.

Is there a way to prevent a driver from being unloaded from the kernel (any callback that catches this event to deny the unload operation) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it since Windows is Controlling it, what you can do it declare the device as NotDisableable in the [WDF_DEVICE_STATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdfdevice/ns-wdfdevice-_wdf_device_state), it is done via `WdfDeviceSetDeviceState()` function

**Example:**

```
WDF_DEVICE_STATE deviceState;
WDF_DEVICE_STATE_INIT(&deviceState);

deviceState.NotDisableable = WdfFalse;
status = WdfDeviceSetDeviceState(Device, &deviceState);
```